# How to replace sections of raster with data from another

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I am trying to replace an attribute of one raster dataset, which generalizes the data over that area, with a collection of attributes from another raster which cover the same area, but provide more specific information.

Is there a way to clip out one attribute of a raster, and replace that section with the attributes of another?

Comment: I think I answered this yesterday https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/247275/selecting-pixels-in-raster-using-polygon-selection-tool/247282#247282 provided you have access to the spatial analyst extension, if not you need to use different software. You would need to draw polygons for 'replace areas' then use that as a binary mask for Con, except in this case instead of using the values of the poly raster it would look like Con(IsNull(PolyRaster),ExistingRaster,UpdateRaster).

Comment: Is it possible to solve this problem without the Spatial Analyst extension?

Comment: Is it possible to solve this problem without the SA extention?  Yes, but you would need to use something like Python to convert the raster to a Numpy array and code the solution, or use the free tools provided by QGIS.

Comment: I think you could do it with arcpy, gdal_calc or gdal in python, definitely with gdal in C#/VB.net or C/C++. If you edit the question to request a non-Esri (or at least not spatial analyst) answer then this thread can be reopened and an alternate solution can be proposed. As it stands a gdal or arcpy answer to an Esri desktop tagged question is likely to attract downvotes as being unacceptable. It might be better to ask a new question requesting alternate answers and reference this tread. Be sure to mention your level of ability in scripting/programming languages (if any).